# using a negative number in the default section of a switch statement as a char

Tags: c#

I'm not looking for any specific code examples, but could someone explain why I can't get the '-1' to function at the end of this switch statement?  It keeps saying that there are "too many literals" for type char. (something close to that).  Would I have to convert this to another type?

Thanks for any help, and please, just explain without giving code.  I would love to learn this by hands on experiance  :D

> Convert 7 char passed from ProcessInput() by reference to upper case
>   Use switch statement to translate char into their corresponding digits (case statement for each digit and each valid uppercase letter)
>   *********TROUBLES WITH THIS PART**********Write default case that returns error code (-1) for invalid letters
>   If no invalide letters, return 0

```
    static void ToDigit(ref char digit)
    {

        digit = Char.ToUpper(digit);
        char result;

        switch (digit)
        {
            case '0':  result = '0';
                break;

            case '1': result = '1';
                break;

            case '2':
            case 'A':
            case 'B':
            case 'C': result = '2';
                break;

            case '3':
            case 'D':
            case 'E':
            case 'F': result = '3';
                break;

            case '4':
            case 'G':
            case 'H':
            case 'I': result = '4';
                break;

            case '5':
            case 'J':
            case 'K':
            case 'L': result = '5';
                break;

            case '6':
            case 'M':
            case 'N':
            case 'O': result = '6';
                break;

            case '7':
            case 'P':
            case 'Q':
            case 'R':
            case 'S': result = '7';
                break;

            case '8':
            case 'T':
            case 'U':
            case 'V': result = '8';
                break;

            case '9':
            case 'W':
            case 'X':
            case 'Y':
            case 'Z': result = '9';
                break;
                //Says I can't enter -1 as char "too many characters in character literal
            default: result = 'e';
                break;
        }
        digit = result;
    }
```

Comment: homework? add the appropriate tag please.

Comment: Your return type is `void` so you obviously can't return anything. You'll need `int` as return type.

Comment: Muad, I had homework and C# down as the tag.  :D

Comment: CodeInChaos,  Thanks for that, I overlooked it while looking at the char problem I'm having.  I will get that changed, thanks a tond. :D

Comment: "Convert 7 char " what is that supposed to mean?

Comment: Char in C# is literally a Unicode character, unlike in C and C++, where it is a single byte with positive and negative values. So in a way, C/C++ char roughly translates to C# byte (which is unsigned) and char, depending on usage.

Comment: As per the instructions, you're supposed to _return_ something. Currently you're returning `void`, and that's your problem. Try returning an int or an otherwise numeric value. Actually, IMO what the instructions say is a bad way of doing things. I would return a char if successful, and throw if not. At least the original wouldn't be mutated if something fails, but that all depends on the calling code.

Comment: @GMMan a C# character is a UTF-16 codeunit, and not a full unicode codepoint.

Comment: CodeInChaos, sorry, that was my short hand in the code for my directions.  Convert the 7 character variables that was passed from ProcessInput() to uppercase.  From there, process the variables that were entered into their corresponding number (like the ABC/123 on a phone pad).  If the characters were invalid/symbols, then return '-1' so it can trigger an error message within another function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `char` is, as the name implies, a *single character*. A group of characters all "strung together" is called a `string` in C#.

If you want the integer value -1 *as a char* then you can do that by saying `unchecked((char)(-1))` (*) but you should be aware that this is a *very bad idea*. I assume that this is your assignment:

> Write default case that returns error code (-1) for invalid letters.

That's not how things work in C#; returning a "bad" value to indicate failure is a "worst practice" -- it is characteristic of 1970's style C programming, but not C#.

The right thing to do here is to either (1) have no error cases at all; if there is no upper case form then just don't transform the character at all, or (2) throw an exception if the input is bad, or (3) return a nullable char, and return null for the "bad" value.

Also, the fact that your program takes a `ref` rather than returning a value is deeply suspicious. A `ToDigit` method should be *computing and returning result* not *mutating a variable*.

I think whatever course of study you are taking was written decades ago, originally targetted a different language entirely, and was never updated to use modern best practices. I would seriously question the value of such materials.

---

Always say `(T)(-1)` in C# when casting the constant `-1` to the type `T`, rather than `(T)-1`. If you write it the latter way, the reader can get confused about whether you mean "subtract one from T" or "cast negative one to type T".

Comment: Trust me, this whole assignment seems to be a bit off and not efficient.  But, I do see why they have us doing certain things.  I wish I could do the above that you mentioned, as I actually used a different char for the error orginally but it is required for the assignment to return '-1'

Comment: "I think whatever course of study you are taking was written decades ago" I wouldn't be sure about that. I've been given worse new code at university.

Comment: `char ch = (char)(-1);` generates the compiler error `Constant value '-1' cannot be converted to a 'char' (use 'unchecked' syntax to override)`

Comment: It doesn't have to be that ancient, [TextReader.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w3csw16.aspx) is described as `int Read()` - reads the next character ...

Comment: I think the intent is a sort of badly specced `bool char.TryParse(out int i)`

Answer (score 3):

Because '-1' isn't a char, it's two separate characters. '-' and '1'.

Comment: So, I would have to find a way to convert the Char before running the code and then convert it back to char after it runs?

Comment: @user1174357 Personally, I would suggest using Eric Lippert's suggestion of returning a "char?" to indicate error, however I realize the requirement is -1, which would indicate you would have to return an integer that represents the ascii character code.

Answer (score 3):

Since it talks about returning `0` on success, I assume that the resulting character, and the return value are different things. So they probably want something like this:

```
static int ToDigit(ref char digit)
{
  switch (Char.ToUpperInvariant(digit))
  {
    case x:
      digit=y;
      return 0;
    ...
    default:
      return -1;
   }
}
```

A few notes:

1. I'm using `ToUpperInvariant` instead of `ToUpper`, since to upper uses the current locale, and that can lead to strange effects. For example your code wouldn't accept an `i` when run on a Turkish computer.
2. I'm leaving `digit` untouched in the error case.
3. Using `int` to represent success/error is a bad idea. Should at least be a `bool`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  This is just a beginner course so the ToUpperINvariant was new to me.  Also, I don't have much experiance with bool atm, we only touched base on basic loop structures and haven't really dealt with bool yet.

Answer (score 2):

You should make result the type `int`, and return it back to the caller. The caller could then compare it to `-1`, and then quickly convert back to digit if it's not -1 by adding `'0'`:

```
int result;
switch (digit) {
    // Assign result here
}
char resDigit;
if (result < 0) {
    // bad digit
} else {
    resDigit = result + '0';
}
```

As a side note, you can replace your switch with a lookup in a long string of characters:

```
string lookup = "0    1    2 ABC3 DEF4 GHI5 JKL6 MNO7PQRS8 TUV9WXYZ";
int pos = lookup.IndexOf(char.ToUpper(digit));
if (pos < 0) {
    // bad digit
} else {
    result = '0' + pos/5;
}
```

Comment: That second way looks fairly neat, sadly, we have to use the switch statement.

Comment: @user1174357 That's OK, I'm sure you'll see an assignment in the future where you could use a similar little trick.

Answer (score 0):

A `char` can contain only one character, thus `'-1'` does not work. `(char)(-1)` is not a valid character value.

My suggestion is to simply use `'?'` as default (or error) value.